# What does 「声室」mean in this context?

Tags: translation

I found the following sentence in a document relating to [this webpage](http://www.fujikasai.co.jp/CGI/news/index.cgi?view=detail&seq=390):

> 「お客さまの**声室**」受付時間を2012年11月3日（土）より以下の通りに変更いたします。

My initial guess is that 「お客さまの声室」 is some kind of feedback room where costumer concerns are voiced out and catered for, but I'm not sure because I can't find an analogous meaning of 「声室」anywhere.

Is "Customer Feedback Room" accurate? Or if I'm wrong, what is the room for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As Tokyo Nagoya pointed out](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14846/4183), the phrase was parsed incorrectly. The correct division is:

> 「お[客様]{きゃくさま}の[声]{こえ}」 + 「[室]{しつ}」

However, regarding translation, it seems that "Customer Service" is a little off since 「お客様相談室」 is a more appropriate term for it, as [Chocolate mentioned.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14844/what-does-%E3%80%8C%E5%A3%B0%E5%AE%A4%E3%80%8Dmean-in-this-context#comment32064_14846) Recently, I realized that the phrase may actually be a very literal translation of `「お客様の声」` from the business concept **[`Voice of the Customer`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_of_the_customer)**.

> <sub>[From Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_of_the_customer)</sub>
>
> "...a market research technique that produces a detailed set of
>   customer wants and needs..."

Using this, I found a [localized site](https://www.aigcustomervoice.co.za/Portal/default.aspx) from the same company that was used in the context of the question. The term **`Customer Voice`** was used.

So, to summarize, `「お客様の声室」` or Customer Voice is a service that serves as an outlet so that feedback— the customer's thoughts and opinions— may be heard.

Answer (score 7):

You are dividing the phrase at the wrong place.

It is 「お[客様]{きゃくさま}の[声]{こえ}」 + 「[室]{しつ}」, not 「お客様の」 + 「声室」

「室」 is often used by Japanese companies and it refers to a "section" of a company offering a particular kind of service.  There may or may not be an actual and physical "room" for the service.  Unless it is a large-scale company, 「お客さまの声室」 is usually not staffed by a full-time team of employees.  Instead, it is run by a few people who spend more time doing other things in the company and when the phone rings at the designated 「お客さまの声室」 number, they answer by saying 「Company name + お客さまの声室でございます。」

For translation, I might just use "Customer Service" without "room".

Comment: 「お客様相談室」のほうがよく見るよね。

Comment: Chocolate has a point. If the set phrase for "Customer Service" is 「お客様相談室」 how is it different from  「お客さまの声室」?

Comment: どう違うか分からないけど、「相談室」と言うと「苦情・困ったことを相談する場所」、「お客様の声室」と言うと「意見・感想・要望を聞いてくれる場所かな？」という、少し気軽な雰囲気があるよね。